# Clustering of very skewed, count data: any suggestions to go about (transform etc)?

Tags: clustering, data-transformation, k-means, count-data, compositional-data

## Basic problem

Here is my basic problem: I am trying to cluster a dataset containing some very skewed variables with counts. The variables contain many zeros and are therefore not very informative for my clustering procedure - which is likely to be k-means algorithm.

Fine, you say, just transform the variables using square root, box cox, or logarithm. 
But since my variables are based on categorical variables, I fear that I might introduce a bias by handling a variable (based on one value of the categorical variable), while leaving others (based on others values of the categorical variable) the way they are.

Let's go into some more detail.

### The dataset

My dataset represents purchases of items. The items have different categories, for example color: blue, red, and green. The purchases are then grouped together, e.g. by customers. Each of these customers is represented by one row of my dataset, so I somehow have to aggregate purchases over customers.

The way I do this is by counting the number of purchases, where the item is a certain color. So instead of a single variable `color`, I end up with three variables `count_red`, `count_blue`, and `count_green`.

Here is an example for illustration:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
customer | count_red  |    count_blue   | count_green     |
-----------------------------------------------------------
c0       |    12      |        5        |       0         |
-----------------------------------------------------------
c1       |     3      |        4        |       0         |
-----------------------------------------------------------
c2       |     2      |       21        |       0         |
-----------------------------------------------------------
c3       |     4      |        8        |       1         |
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

Actually, I do not use absolute counts in the end, I use ratios (fraction of green items of all purchased items per customer).

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
customer | count_red  |    count_blue   | count_green     |
-----------------------------------------------------------
c0       |    0.71    |        0.29     |       0.00      |
-----------------------------------------------------------
c1       |    0.43    |        0.57     |       0.00      |
-----------------------------------------------------------
c2       |    0.09    |        0.91     |       0.00      |
-----------------------------------------------------------
c3       |    0.31    |        0.62     |       0.08      |
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

The result is the same: For one of my colors, e.g. green (nobody likes green), I get a left-skewed variable containing many zeros. Consequently, k-means fails to find a good partitioning for this variable.

On the other hand, if I standardize my variables (subtract mean, divide by standard deviation), the green variable "blows up" due to its small variance and takes values from a much larger range than the other variables, which makes it look more important to k-means than it actually is.

The next idea is to transform the sk(r)ewed green variable.

### Transforming the skewed variable

If I transform the green variable by applying the square root it looks a little less skewed. (Here the green variable is plotted in red and green to ensure confusion.)

[image]

Red: original variable; blue: transformed by square root.

Let's say I am satisfied with the result of this transformation (which I am not, since the zeros still strongly skew the distribution). Should I now also scale the red and blue variables, although their distributions look fine?

## Bottom line

In other words, do I distort the clustering results by handling the color green on one way, but not handling red and blue at all? In the end, all three variables belong together, so shouldn't they be handled in the same way?

## EDIT

To clarify: I am aware that k-means is probably not the way to go for *count-based* data. My question however really is about the treatment of dependent variables. Choosing the correct method is a separate matter.

The inherent constraint in my variables is that

`count_red(i) + count_blue(i) + count_green(i) = n(i)`, where `n(i)` is the total number of purchases of customer `i`.

(Or, equivalently, `count_red(i) + count_blue(i) + count_green(i) = 1` when using relative counts.)

If I transform my variables differently, this corresponds to giving different weights to the three terms in the constraint. If my goal is to optimally separate groups of customers, do I have to care about violating this constraint? Or does "the end justify the means"?

Comment: Welcome to CV! Thank you for making your first question so clear and well-written.

Comment: I did not quite understand your dataset. The variables (attributes) are `count_red`, `count_blue` and `count_green` and the data are counts. Right? What are the rows then - items? And you are going to cluster the items?

Comment: The rows generally represent groups of aggregated purchases. You can think of them as customers who bought multiple items. I have updated my question with a sample dataset to make this more clear.

Comment: You want to cluster "customers"?

Comment: Yes. I intend to group purchases by time intervals as well and consequently cluster time intervals, but for now: customers.

Answer (score 15):

It is not wise to transform the variables individually because they belong together (as you noticed) and to do k-means because the data are counts (you might, but k-means is better to do on continuous attributes such as length for example).

In your place, I would compute chi-square distance (perfect for counts) between every pair of customers, based on the variables containing counts. Then do hierarchical clustering (for example, average linkage method or complete linkage method - they do not compute centroids and threfore don't require euclidean distance) or some other clustering working with arbitrary distance matrices.

Copying example data from the question:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
customer | count_red  |    count_blue   | count_green     |
-----------------------------------------------------------
c0       |    12      |        5        |       0         |
-----------------------------------------------------------
c1       |     3      |        4        |       0         |
-----------------------------------------------------------
c2       |     2      |       21        |       0         |
-----------------------------------------------------------
c3       |     4      |        8        |       1         |
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

Consider pair `c0` and `c1` and compute **Chi-square** statistic for their `2x3` frequency table. Take the square root of it (like you take it when you compute usual euclidean distance). That is your distance. If the distance is close to 0 the two customers are similar.

It may bother you that sums in rows in your table differ and so it affects the chi-square distance when you compare `c0` with `c1` vs `c0` with `c2`. Then compute the (root of) the **Phi-square** distance: `Phi-sq = Chi-sq/N` where `N` is the combined total count in the two rows (customers) currently considered. It is thus normalized distance wrt to overall counts.

```
Here is the matrix of sqrt(Chi-sq) distance between your four customers
 .000   1.275   4.057   2.292
1.275    .000   2.124    .862
4.057   2.124    .000   2.261
2.292    .862   2.261    .000

And here is the matrix of sqrt(Phi-sq) distance 
.000    .260    .641    .418
.260    .000    .388    .193
.641    .388    .000    .377
.418    .193    .377    .000
```

So, the distance between any two rows of the data is the (sq. root of) the **chi-square** or **phi-square statistic** of the `2 x p` frequency table (`p` is the number of columns in the data). If any column(s) in the current `2 x p` table is complete zero, cut off that column and compute the distance based on the remaining nonzero columns (it is OK and this is how, for example, SPSS does when it computes the distance). Chi-square distance is actually a weighted euclidean distance.

Comment: Thank you for this elaborate answer. I appreciate you gave advice on something that was not my original question: Is K-means (with the implicit Euclidean distance) the right choice for this use case? I suspected it is not, and you confirmed that.
However, I still don't unterstand **why**. Could you reason
1) why chi-square (or phi-square) distance is a good choice for count data?
2) coming back to my original question: is there a good (mathematical/empirical) argument why all variables should be treated the same way other than "they belong together"?

Comment: A customer chooses among the three colours when he makes a single purchase: the three colours are not conceptually independent "variables". Plus your data are counts. It was immediately clear to me that a chi-square based measure should be optimal. In regard to your last point - I could ask you back: why should they be treated differently? A gave you a solution to do the clustering job. Is there anything in it what you don't like or what makes you doubt?

Comment: I also don't think k-means (variance minimization!) is the way to go: k-means uses *means*. Your data are integers, and have many zeros. The cluster centers will not be integers, and will have few zeros. They are totally *unlike* your data points, how can they be representative? Bottom line: don't fight to transform your data to fit k-means. Understand the problem, and fit the algorithms to your problem, not the other way. If you fit your data to the k-means problem, it may still be the wrong problem...

Comment: @ttnphns No, I don't doubt your solution, I actually think it is the better approach. But I was not coming here for a solution to follow blindly, I want to **understand why** it is a better clustering strategy. And again, my original question was not about a better algorithm, but rather "Do I destroy fundamental properties of my data if I transform dependent variables differently?" In the end, my goal is to optimally separate my customers, and my above transformation of the green variable lets me at least distinguish between "buys no green at all" and "buys green".

Comment: @Anony-Mousse You are probably right that k-means is not the right choice got my kind of data. However, I think the fact that my variables contain lots of zeros is more important than the fact they are integers. (As I noted in my question, I use relative counts in the end, so I will get number in the range [0,1])

Comment: When you standardize your variables to equilize their variances it is roughly equivalent to equalizing the totals in the columns of your data table. When you transform the skew it is roughly equivalent to boost larger but not smaller counts in your table. You may do it (and even after it you may compute chi or phi as I've suggested), but be aware that you've twisted original data. Was it warranted, did you uncover and not conceal valuable information? Was it unnecessary torturing of the data? In the end, you are the only one who decides on these reflections.

Comment: @ttnphns Now you got me thinking! I think I am starting to understand what this is doing to my data. But I think it is the other way round: If I sqrt-transform values between 0 and 1, smaller number will be amplified more than larger numbers. So I artificially separate the zeros from the non-zeros in the green variable. And you are right, in the end I have to decide if this is valid by myself - but nevertheless, your input is highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: If, after all that, you will find my limited answer to be partly relevant you might consider accepting and/or voting it :-)

Comment: It's easy to destroy fundamental properties by inappropriate normalization. E.g. if your data sums up to 1 in each row, normalizing each column will destroy this property. On such data, you should consider e.g. divergence measures (distances for distributions) instead. On counting data, set intersection measures such as Jaccard may be more informative; but they need binary vectors. etc.

Comment: @ttnphns -What is the formula for chi-square, I am  trying to get the same result as you, but no success

Comment: @MPA, for each pair of rows, usual chi-square statistic of independence is computed (2 rows x 3 columns frequency cross-table) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test#Testing_for_statistical_independence

Comment: @ttnphns - I am cannot understand the formula, please, can you give example of the 2 rows? I am really appreciate

Comment: @MPA, go to https://www.socscistatistics.com/tests/chisquare2/default2.aspx (or other numerous online chi-square calculators). For comparison of, say, `c0` with `c1` customers, enter there this 2x2 table `12, 5; 3, 4` (column `count_green` - skip it because it is complete empty). You will get chi-square statistic= 1.6269, which square is `1.275` displayed in my answer. Good luck to you.

Comment: @ttnphns - Thanks

Answer (score 11):

@ttnphns has provided a good answer.

Doing clustering well is often about thinking very hard about your data, so let's do some of that.  To my mind, the most fundamental aspect of your data is that they are [compositional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compositional_data).

On the other hand, your primary concern seems to be that you have a lot of 0s for green products and specifically wonder if you can transform only the green values to make it more similar to the rest.  But because these are compositional data, you cannot think about one set of counts independently from the rest.  Moreover, it appears that what you are really interested in are customers' probabilities of purchasing different colored products, but because many have not purchased any green ones, you worry that you cannot estimate those probabilities.  One way to address this is to use a somewhat Bayesian approach in which we nudge customers' estimated proportions towards a mean proportion, with the amount of the shift influenced by how far they are from the mean and how much data you have to estimate their true probabilities.

Below I use your example dataset to illustrate (in R) one way to approach your situation.  I read in the data and convert them into rowwise proportions, and then compute mean proportions by column.  I add the means back to each count to get adjusted counts and new rowwise proportions.  This nudges each customer's estimated proportion towards the mean proportion for each product.  If you wanted a stronger nudge, you could use a multiple of the means (such as, `15*mean.props`) instead.

```r
d = read.table(text="id  red    blue    green
...
c3  4   8   1", header=TRUE)
tab = as.table(as.matrix(d[,-1]))
rownames(tab) = paste0("c", 0:3)
tab
#    red blue green
# c0  12    5     0
# c1   3    4     0
# c2   2   21     0
# c3   4    8     1
props = prop.table(tab, 1)
props
#           red       blue      green
# c0 0.70588235 0.29411765 0.00000000
# c1 0.42857143 0.57142857 0.00000000
# c2 0.08695652 0.91304348 0.00000000
# c3 0.30769231 0.61538462 0.07692308
mean.props = apply(props, 2, FUN=function(x){ weighted.mean(x, rowSums(tab)) })
mean.props
#        red       blue      green 
# 0.35000000 0.63333333 0.01666667 
adj.counts = sweep(tab, 2, mean.props, FUN="+");  adj.counts
#            red        blue       green
# c0 12.35000000  5.63333333  0.01666667
# c1  3.35000000  4.63333333  0.01666667
# c2  2.35000000 21.63333333  0.01666667
# c3  4.35000000  8.63333333  1.01666667
adj.props = prop.table(adj.counts, 1);  adj.props
#             red         blue        green
# c0 0.6861111111 0.3129629630 0.0009259259
# c1 0.4187500000 0.5791666667 0.0020833333
# c2 0.0979166667 0.9013888889 0.0006944444
# c3 0.3107142857 0.6166666667 0.0726190476
```

There are several results of this.  One of which is that you now have non-zero estimates of the underlying probabilities of purchasing green products, even when a customer doesn't actually have any record of having purchased any green products yet.  Another consequence is that you now have somewhat continuous values, whereas the original proportions were more discrete; that is, the set of possible estimates is less constricted, so a distance measure like the squared Euclidean distance *might* make more sense now.

We can visualize the data to see what happened.  Because these are compositional data, we only actually have two pieces of information, and we can plot these in a single scatterplot.  With most of the information in the red and blue categories, it makes sense to use those as the axes.  You can see that the adjusted proportions (the red numbers) are shifted a little from their original positions.

```r
windows()
  plot(props[,1], props[,2], pch=as.character(0:3),
       xlab="Proportion Red", ylab="Proportion Blue", xlim=c(0,1), ylim=c(0,1))
  points(adj.props[,1], adj.props[,2], pch=as.character(0:3), col="red")
```

[image]

At this point, you have data and a lot of people would begin by standardizing them.  Again, because these are compositional data, I would run cluster analyses without doing any standardization—these values are already commensurate and standardization would destroy some of the relational information.  In fact, from looking at the plot I think you really have only one dimension of information here.  (At least in the sample dataset; your real dataset may well be different.)  Unless, from a business point of view, you think it's important to recognize people who have any substantial probability of purchasing green products as a distinct cluster of customers, I would extract scores on the first principal component (which accounts for 99.5% of the variance in this dataset) and just cluster that.

```r
pc.a.props = prcomp(adj.props[,1:2], center=T, scale=T)
cumsum(pc.a.props$sdev^2)/sum(pc.a.props$sdev^2)
# [1] 0.9946557 1.000000
pc.a.props$x
#           PC1         PC2
# c0 -1.7398975 -0.03897251
# c1 -0.1853614 -0.04803648
# c2  1.6882400 -0.06707115
# c3  0.2370189  0.15408015
library(mclust)
mc = Mclust(pc.a.props$x[,1])
summary(mc)
# ----------------------------------------------------
# Gaussian finite mixture model fitted by EM algorithm 
# ----------------------------------------------------
# 
# Mclust E (univariate, equal variance) model with 3 components:
# 
#  log.likelihood n df       BIC       ICL
#       -2.228357 4  6 -12.77448 -12.77448
# 
# Clustering table:
# 1 2 3 
# 1 2 1
```

Comment: +1 because you recognised that this is compositional data but why would you not just use standard transformation techniques for compos. data instead of this odd "mean adjusted counts" idea? It seems ad-hoc to me, is there a particular reference for this or something similar? Why is this better than a simple centred log-ratio transform and then clustering first PC score of the transformed data? (which would be what any reasonable reviewer of a compos. data analysis application would ask)

Comment: Thanks, @usεr11852. Counts of >2, but finite, options are multinomials. This is (1 form of an empirical) Bayesian analysis w/ a [Dirichlet prior](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/44495/7290) (the conjugate). I'm sure other options are possible. I don't immediately see how taking ratios would work w/ the 0s, however.

Comment: Thanks for link. If you have a single non-zero component dimension you could use it for an additive log-ratio transform (excluding the obvious idea of imputation; see comments [here](http://www.stat.boogaart.de/Publications/iamg06_s07_01.pdf)). The CLR would be off, because it uses a geometric mean. There has been work on "zero-inflated compositional data"; see for example [here](http://rd.springer.com/article/10.1007/s13253-010-0040-8), [here](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1467-9868.2010.00766.x) and [here](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1556-4029.2009.01316.x).

Comment: It sounds like you know a lot more about this topic than I do, @usεr11852. My answer was really just trying to make these facts about the nature of the situation explicit / raise the issue & provide a preliminary suggestion. Why not contribute your own (better informed) answer?