# Similarity between bar plots (counts of categories)?

Tags: probability, categorical-data, similarities, jaccard-similarity

What are the best ways to compare (calculate similarity) between two bar plots? For example:

```
a = {apple: 2, orange: 10, grape: 1}
b = {apple: 1, cucumber: 2, apricot: 3, avocado: 2}
Similarity (a,b) = ?
```

I want to compare `a` and `b`. The things which come to my mind are **Jaccard simlarity** and **Cross Entropy**.  Are there any better options?

Comment: You mean clustered barcharts, don't you?

Comment: See [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/173669/3277) answer and other answers there.

Comment: I meant: you have 2 vectors length 6 with counts (some counts are 0). Consider it as 2x6 frequency cross-table and compute chi-sq distance or phi-sq distance as explained in the answer I linked to.

Comment: @ttnphns, do you think this is a duplicate?

Comment: gung, I don't know. That older question is more rich and specific. Maybe a duplicate, maybe not.

Comment: @ ttnps and @gong, I agree the **chi square distance** is a suitable option. Are there any additional or more sophisticated options?